# Search for a record where a value is between two item fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a MondoDB collection with over 5 million items. Each item has a "start" and "end" fields containing integer values.

Items don't have overlapping starts and ends.

e.g. this would be **invalid**:

```
{start:100, end:200}
{start:150, end:250}
```

I am trying to locate an item where a given value is between start and end

```
start <= VALUE <= end
```

The following query works, but it takes 5 to 15 seconds to return

```
db.blocks.find({ "start" : { $lt : 3232235521 }, "end" :{ $gt : 3232235521 }}).limit(1);
```

I've added the following indexes for testing with very little improvement

```
db.blocks.ensureIndex({start:1});
db.blocks.ensureIndex({end:1});

//also a compounded one
db.blocks.ensureIndex({start:1,end:1});
```

** Edit **

The result of explain() on the query results in:

```
> db.blocks.find({ "start" : { $lt : 3232235521 }, "end" :{ $gt : 3232235521 }}).limit(1).explain();

{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor end_1",
        "nscanned" : 1160982,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1160982,
        "n" : 0,
        "millis" : 5779,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "end" : [
                        [
                                3232235521,
                                1.7976931348623157e+308
                        ]
                ]
        }
}
```

What would be the best approach to speeding this specific query up?

Comment: Did you try to run an explain command to see what is the `nscanned` number for your query ? It might be that your query critera is qualifying  loads of documents for `start` and then finding `end` and vice versa. Btw are the intervals fixed eg 0-99,100-199? or variable ?

Comment: I think you're on to something.. nscanned is huge (added to the question). The intervals are not fixed, they're variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess compbound index should work faster for you:

```
db.blocks.ensureIndex({start:1, end:1});
```

You can also use [explain](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain) to see number of scanned object, etc and choose best index.

Also if you are using mongodb < 2.0 you need to update to 2.0+, because there indexes [work faster](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.0+Release+Notes#2.0ReleaseNotes-IndexPerformanceEnhancements). 
Also you can [limit](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Blimit%28%29%7D%7D) results to optimize query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. I had actually already tried a compound index and also used hint(..) to make sure it was being used. explain() confirmed that it was. .limit(1) cut some queries in half, but I'm still seeing 4-5 second queries. I'm using the latest mongo 2.*

Comment: I had updated to mongo 2.0 from 1.6, but I was still using the same data path.. I started mongod with a new dbpath, re-imported the data and created the indexes (single and compound). Now queries average 10ms :)

Comment: @JuanD: hmm, strange. docs says that update to mongodb 2.0 should work without reimporting of data and rebuilding of indexes. in any good that you've figured it out!

Comment: See rendybjunior answer. It is a lot faster if the range hit miss.

Answer (score 4):

actually I'm working on similar problem and my friend find a nice way to solve this.

If you don't have overlapping data, you can do this:

1. query using **start field** and **sort function**
2. validate with end field

for example you can do

```
var x = 100;
var results = db.collection.find({start:{$lte:x}}).sort({start:-1}).limit(1)
if (results!=null) {
  var result = results[0];
  if (result.end > x) {
    return result;
  } else {
    return null; // no range contain x
  } 
}
```

If you are sure that there will always range containing x, then you do not have to validate the result.

By using this piece of code, **you only have to index by either start or end field** and your query become a lot faster.

--- edit

I did some benchmark, using composite index takes 100-100,000ms per query, in the other hand using one index takes 1-5ms per query.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: how about you introduce some redundancy. If there is not a big variance in the lengths of the intervals, then you can introduce a tag field for each record - this tag field is a single value or string that represents a large interval - say for example tag 50,000 is used to tag all records with intervals that are at least partially in the range 0-50,000 and tag 100,000 is for all intervals in the range 50,000-100,000, and so on. Now you can index on the tag as primary and one of the end points of record range as secondary.

Records on the edge of big interval would have more than one tag - so we are talking [multikeys](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys). On your query you would of course calculate the big interval tag and use it in the query.

You would roughly want SQRT of total records per tag - just a starting point for tests, then you can fine tune the big interval size.

Of course this would make writing bit slower.