# multiple greater than in query with compound index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of CIDR ranges with the following schema:

```
{ bottom: Number
top: Number
cidrText: String
live: Boolean
hits: Number }
```

What I am trying to do is to find if an ip is within the bottom + top ranges (and then perform a $inc update on the hits on that record.

At the moment my index is:

```
db.tbl.ensureIndex( { bottom: 1, top: 1, live: 1 } );
```

But when I run my query - only part of the query uses the index and then this has a large impact on my servers performance:

My query is:

```
db.tbl.find({ live: true, top: { $gte: 3266341261 }, bottom: { $lte: 3266341261 } })
```

The explain output is:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor top_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 0,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 7,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "top" : [
            [
                3266341261,
                1.7976931348623157e+308
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "local:27017"
}
```

Is there a way I can get both $gte and $lte to use the same index - or should I run 2 queries and find a row that matches in both queries?

**Edit**
I have dropped all existing indices and re-added the compound index and now I get correct bounds, but nscanned is still high.

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor bottom_1_top_1_live_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 4748,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 4746,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 9494,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 15,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "bottom" : [
            [
                -1.7976931348623157e+308,
                3633904421
            ]
        ],
        "top" : [
            [
                3633904421,
                1.7976931348623157e+308
            ]
        ],
        "live" : [
            [
                true,
                true
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "local27017"
}
```

Also I get this in my log:

```
warning: ClientCursor::yield can't unlock b/c of recursive lock ns: col.tbl top: { opid: 25701683, active: true, secs_running: 0, op: "query", ns: "tbl", query: { findandmodify: "tbl", query: { live: true, top: { $gte: 1584813140 }, bottom: { $lte: 1584813140 } }, sort: {}, new: 1, remove: 0, upsert: 0, update: { $inc: { hits: 1 } } }, client: "127.0.0.1:39407", desc: "conn581", threadId: "0x497ec940", connectionId: 581, locks: { ^: "w", ^tbl: "W" }, waitingForLock: false, numYields: 0, lockStats: { timeLockedMicros: {}, timeAcquiringMicros: { r: 0, w: 3 } } }
```

**Edit 2**

Too clear up the "order of find parameters" is does look like the order of the search term **does** need to match the index order (atleast in 2.4.4). Running these 2 queries - one uses the full index the other does not.

```
> db.tbl.find({top: {$lte: 1454442030}, bottom: {$gte: 1454442030}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor top_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2271,
    "nscanned" : 2271,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 6816,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 11396,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 24,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "top" : [
            [
                -1.7976931348623157e+308,
                1454442030
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "local:27017"
}
```

and

```
> db.tbl.find({bottom: {$lte: 1454442030}, top: {$gte: 1454442030}}).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor bottom_1_top_1_live_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 2,
    "nscannedObjects" : 2,
    "nscanned" : 2080,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 6240,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 10400,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 23,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "bottom" : [
            [
                -1.7976931348623157e+308,
                1454442030
            ]
        ],
        "top" : [
            [
                1454442030,
                1.7976931348623157e+308
            ]
        ],
        "live" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "local:27017"
}
```

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Seems like this is the same question and issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061022/search-for-a-record-where-a-value-is-between-two-item-fields-in-mongodb

Comment: The `explain` output is odd -- nothing was scanned?

Comment: Could you reorder your `find` query to match the order of the compound index?

Comment: @WiredPrairie the order in find is completely irrelevant - only order of the index matters.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - The docs are very careful to always order it in a matching sequence (I wish the docs were more clear and absolute about this).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky - at least the `explain` as shown is listing them in the order specified by the `ensureIndex` call. That's reasonable confirmation.

Comment: the docs are clear that order of index matters - if there is anything that suggests that find({a:1,b:2}) and find({b:2,a:1}) are in any way treated differently that would need to be fixed as that is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the number of scanned index entries is high is because of the order of selectivity of keys in your compound index.   The order of the entries in the index matters a lot both for which queries the index can be used for, but also to the number of index entries the query has to scan.

If it is the case that the percentage of entries in your collection which have `live=true` is very low you would be better off constructing your compound index with "live" as the first key - since any query which has live=true will be highly selective.

Without knowing your data distribution and your query patterns it's hard to know for sure what is the right approach but as a general rule, if you have a choice about the order of fields you want to put most selective keys first and least selective ones last.

Answer (score 0):

The warning has nothing to do with this find() query.

Also, why don't you think that nscanned should not be high ?

Basically { bottom: { $lte: 3266341261 } } will have to check all index records matching this, and then has to apply the { top: { $gte: 3266341261 } } filter. Check the index boundaries in explaing() which I guess is applied as expected and correctly.

Can you run following. It should be close to { "nscanned" : 4748 }

```
db.tbl.find({ bottom: { $lte: 3266341261 } }).explain()
```

Comment: the result of this is: "nscanned" : 4683,
running with no find value 'find()' results in: "nscanned" : 5317

Comment: If the value is 4683, then nscanned for your original question has to be high. nscanned is the total index entries that has to be scanned. I am guessing you are not confusing with nscannedObjects